# Only 1 onClickListener works on markers in google maps activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent

So in short we have an activty with a google maps map and we pu a lat of markers on them. Now we want to be able to click all these markers. We use an onClickListeners for that.

```
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
              if (marker.getTitle().equals("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")) {
                  Intent AlmaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acz.class);
                  startActivity(AlmaIntent);
                  return false;
              }
              return false;
          }
      }
    );


    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ecolab)
            .title("Ecolab")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
              if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ecolab")) {
                  Intent ecolabIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_ecolab.class);
                  startActivity(ecolabIntent);
                  return false;
              }
              return false;
          }
      }
    );
```

So this is an example of 2 of our locations. So all the markers are displayed on the map and every location has the same structure of code. The problem is that if we test this, only the last location's marker is clickable. In this case the ecolab marker. How can we make it so that all the markers are clickable.

Somebody else asked a similar problem on here and the answer was that he had 2 setContentView(). This isn't the case with us.

Edit:

```
package com.example.discoverkoelak;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;






import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.AutocompleteSessionToken;

import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MapS extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> predictionList;

    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 18;



    private View mapView;
    private Marker kaka;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kaart);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapS.this);
        Places.initialize(MapS.this, ("MY_API_KEY"));





        final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        int height = 100;
        int width = 100;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        //Code die markers zet en ze klikbaar maakt.
        //Hal A
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HalA)
                .title("Hal A")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, hala.class);
                      startActivity(halaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stuvo)
                .title("Stuvo")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                if (marker.getTitle().equals("Stuvo")) {
                    Intent stuvoIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_secstuvo.class);
                    startActivity(stuvoIntent);
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bib)
                .title("Bib")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Bib")) {
                      Intent bibIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_onthaalbib.class);
                      startActivity(bibIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(acco)
                .title("Acco boekenhandel")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Acco boekenhandel")) {
                      Intent accoIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acco.class);
                      startActivity(accoIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(rectoraat)
                .title("Hal Rectoraat")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal Rectoraat")) {
                      Intent rectoraatIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_rectoraat.class);
                      startActivity(rectoraatIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spina)
                .title("Spina")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Spina")) {
                      Intent spinaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_spina.class);
                      startActivity(spinaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stilleRuimte)
                .title("Stille ruimte")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Stille ruimte")) {
                      Intent stilIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_stil.class);
                      startActivity(stilIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(A301)
                .title("Aula Stijn Streuvels (A301)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Aula Stijn Streuvels (A301)")) {
                      Intent A301Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_A301.class);
                      startActivity(A301Intent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(weetkelder)
                .title("Weetkelder")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Weetkelder")) {
                      Intent weetkelderIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_weetkelder.class);
                      startActivity(weetkelderIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fietsena)
                .title("FietsenA")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("FietsenA")) {
                      Intent fietsenaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_fietsena.class);
                      startActivity(fietsenaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(labos)
                .title("Labo's (gang 3)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Labo's (gang 3)")) {
                      Intent labosIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_labo.class);
                      startActivity(labosIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        //gebouw B
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(B422)
                .title("B422")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("B422")) {
                      Intent B422Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_b422.class);
                      startActivity(B422Intent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(puc)
                .title("puc")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("puc")) {
                      Intent pucIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_puc.class);
                      startActivity(pucIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        //gebouw c
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(C611)
                .title("C611")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("C611")) {
                      Intent C611Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_c611.class);
                      startActivity(C611Intent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gang7)
                .title("Gang 7")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Gang 7")) {
                      Intent gang7Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_kantoren.class);
                      startActivity(gang7Intent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        //gebouw E
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(E1001)
                .title("Aula Andreas Vesalius (E1001)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Aula Andreas Vesalius (E1001)")) {
                      Intent E1001Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_e1001.class);
                      startActivity(E1001Intent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vaardigheidscentrum)
                .title("Vaardigheidscentrum")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Vaardigheidscentrum")) {
                      Intent vaardigheidscentrumIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_vaardigheid.class);
                      startActivity(vaardigheidscentrumIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(IRF)
                .title("IRF")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("IRF")) {
                      Intent IRFIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_irf.class);
                      startActivity(IRFIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fietsene)
                .title("fietsene")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("fietsene")) {
                      Intent fietseneIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_fietsene.class);
                      startActivity(fietseneIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        //residenties
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spoelberg)
                .title("Spoelberg")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Spoelberg")) {
                      Intent spoelbergIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_spoelberg.class);
                      startActivity(spoelbergIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(studentendorp)
                .title("Studentendorp")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Studentendorp")) {
                      Intent studentendorpIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_studentendorp.class);
                      startActivity(studentendorpIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
            }
         );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(corona)
                .title("Corona")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Corona")) {
                      Intent coronaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_corona.class);
                      startActivity(coronaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        //andere
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(IICK)
                .title("IICK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("IICK")) {
                      Intent IICKIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_iick.class);
                      startActivity(IICKIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(almaZweetkelder)
                        .title("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")) {
                      Intent AlmaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acz.class);
                      startActivity(AlmaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ecolab)
                .title("Ecolab")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ecolab")) {
                      Intent ecolabIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_ecolab.class);
                      startActivity(ecolabIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );










        if(mapView != null && mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null)  {
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,40,180);

        }

        // kijken of gps signaal aanstaat
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MapS.this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnSuccessListener(MapS.this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(MapS.this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if(e instanceof  ResolvableApiException) {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try{
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MapS.this, 51);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}





        );


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        }


    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            } else {
                                final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                                locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
                                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
                                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                        if (locationResult == null) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                                    }
                                };
                                mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapS.this, "Laatste gekende locatie kan niet worden ontvangen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post complete code?

Comment: complete code of your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
              if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ecolab")) {
                  Intent ecolabIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_ecolab.class);
                  startActivity(ecolabIntent);
              }

              else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")) {
                  Intent AlmaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acz.class);
                  startActivity(AlmaIntent);
              }
              return true;
          }
     }
);
```

Comment: this worked for the 2, i'll try and add more. Thanks already for the help

Comment: if my answer helped you then please accept my answer and upvote it

Comment: can't upvote yet, something about that I don't have enough points

Comment: please don't add important information with question as you added map api with question